# Error Webforms UnobtrusiveValidationMode when application is published on iis

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2013, webforms, iis-7, web-config

My web form application works fine when it's run in Visual Studio 2013. I published the same application on iis version 6.1.
It's giving the following error.
Webforms UnobtrusiveValidationMode requires a ScriptResourceMapping for 'jquery'. Please add a ScriptResourceMapping named jquery(case-sensitive).

I already have check with multiple solutions given on stackoverflow. most of them suggested to add following line in appsetting in web.config file. 
`<add key="ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode" value="WebForms" />`
or change the following from 4.5 to 4.0. but it's futile.

```
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
```

Even this could not helped me to find a solution. What is causing this error? and how can this me resolved?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add following configuration in your Web.config file which is going to enable pre-4.5 validation mode. Since `None` is **not** its default value if you are using `targetFramework="4.5"` you have to explicitly add this to your configuration.

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode" value="None" />
</appSettings>
```

Comment: Have you tried recycling your ASP.NET application right after the configuration was changed?

Comment: No, What's that? Please guide.

Comment: Here is the documentation for IIS Application Pool Recycling: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770764(v=ws.10).aspx